# Selenium Grid Hub/Crash when invoking WIN10 ChromeOption

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have a Selenium hub with the 6 nodes registered as follows based on the platform:

- 3 platfom as WIN10

  ```
  Capabilities {browserName: chrome, extension.sikuliCapability: true, maxInstances: 7, platform: WIN10, platformName: WIN10, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:CONFIG_UUID: ae7939e1-25ff-4030-8baf-efe..., version: ANY}
  ```
- 3 platform as VISTA

  ```
  Capabilities {browserName: chrome, extension.sikuliCapability: true, maxInstances: 7, platform: VISTA, platformName: VISTA, seleniumProtocol: WebDriver, server:..., version: ANY}
  ```

Is there a way to invoke a chrome browser on a platform by mentioning the OSname i have tried a few options but it looks like hub invokes the drives randomly not based on the os version.

Any insight would be helpful. In some instances the chrome driver crashes when i mention the Chrome driver with WIN10 as below:

```
SessionId not found. Running the test locally?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.webDriver' defined in class path resource [application-context-web.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getWebDriver' threw exception; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00D7D383+3134339]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C6A171+2007409]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B0AEE8+569064]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0358+197464]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AAFDC8+196040]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0CB7+199863]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0C1D+199709]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AAEB0B+191243]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A92E77+77431]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A93E3E+81470]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A93DC9+81353]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C80CD9+2100441]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEB75A+1396954]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEB3D9+1396057]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF7126+1444518]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEBCE8+1398376]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C77F51+2064209]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C822EB+2106091]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C82411+2106385]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C949C4+2181572]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77306359+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77647C24+228]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77647BF4+180]

Command duration or timeout: 598 milliseconds
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
        at <packagename>.ThreadScope.get(ThreadScope.java:28)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        at <packagename>.getTargetObject(PUtils.java:14)
        at <packagename>.setUp(BaseSelTestCase.java:127)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:514)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:215)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:589)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getWebDriver' threw exception; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00D7D383+3134339]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C6A171+2007409]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B0AEE8+569064]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0358+197464]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AAFDC8+196040]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0CB7+199863]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0C1D+199709]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AAEB0B+191243]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A92E77+77431]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A93E3E+81470]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A93DC9+81353]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C80CD9+2100441]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEB75A+1396954]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEB3D9+1396057]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF7126+1444518]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEBCE8+1398376]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C77F51+2064209]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C822EB+2106091]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C82411+2106385]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C949C4+2181572]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77306359+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77647C24+228]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77647BF4+180]

Command duration or timeout: 598 milliseconds
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'XGHSGHSG', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x00D7D383+3134339]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C6A171+2007409]
        Ordinal0 [0x00B0AEE8+569064]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0358+197464]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AAFDC8+196040]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0CB7+199863]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AB0C1D+199709]
        Ordinal0 [0x00AAEB0B+191243]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A92E77+77431]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A93E3E+81470]
        Ordinal0 [0x00A93DC9+81353]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C80CD9+2100441]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEB75A+1396954]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEB3D9+1396057]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EF7126+1444518]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00EEBCE8+1398376]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C77F51+2064209]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C822EB+2106091]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C82411+2106385]
        Ordinal0 [0x00C949C4+2181572]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x77306359+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77647C24+228]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77647BF4+180]
```

The node are registered as follows:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [{
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 4,
          "version": "ANY",
          "platform": "WIN10",
          "firefox_binary":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",
          "extension.sikuliCapability": true
        },
        {
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
          "browserName": "chrome",
          "maxInstances": 7,
          "version": "ANY",
          "platform": "WIN10"
        },
        {
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
          "browserName": "internet explorer",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "version": "11",
          "platform": "WIN10"
        },
        {
          "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
          "browserName": "MicrosoftEdge",
          "maxInstances": 1,
          "version": "ANY",
          "platform": "WIN10"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 7,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://hubname:4444/hub/wd/",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
}
```

and

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [{
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "maxInstances": 4,
    "version": "ANY",
    "marionette":true,
    "platform": "VISTA",
    "platformName": "VISTA",
    "firefox_binary":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe",
    "extension.sikuliCapability": true
  },
    {
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 7,
      "version": "ANY",
      "platform": "VISTA",
      "extension.sikuliCapability": true
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 7,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://callisto.quiacorp.com:4444/hub/wd/",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : ["io.sterodium.extensions.node.SikuliExtensionServlet","io.sterodium.extensions.node.upload.FileUploadServlet","io.sterodium.extensions.node.download.FileDownloadServlet"],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Any help in resolving the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
SessionId not found. Running the test locally?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.webDriver' defined in class path resource [application-context-web.xml]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver]: Factory method 'getWebDriver' threw exception; nested exception is org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to communicate with the *Browsing Context* i.e. *Browser* session on `WIN10`.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Though you are using *Selenium version: `'3.141.59`'*.
- Your *`java.version: '1.8.0_101'`*  which is old and ancient.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u251](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I tried with the JDK 11 but i still see this WIN10
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: No matching capabilities found
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.7'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
 Ordinal0 [0x008CD383+3134339]
 Ordinal0 [0x007BA171+2007409]
 Ordinal0 [0x0065AEE8+569064]
 Ordinal0 [0x00600358+197464]